# Searching through a large text or log file (10GB+)

Tags: python, file-read

Part of a Python script that I'm writing requires me to find a particular string in a large text or log file: if it exists then do something; otherwise, do something else.

The files  which are being fed in are extremely large (10GB+). It feels extremely slow and inefficient to use:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if some_string in line:
            return True
    return False
```

If the string doesn't exist in the file, then iterating through would take a long time.

Is there a time efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: you can look into `Dask` or throw it into a database (upfront I/O cost) and use a SQL engine to parse your result.

Comment: What more can you tell us about the file and the string? And how long does it take now and how long would be acceptable?

Comment: @Manakin I'm not immediately convinced of the usefulness of `Dask` here. The SQL approach could be useful, but unfortunately given what I'm doing this would not scale too well with log files and users within my organisation.

Comment: @KellyBundy The log file is the typical output of the `logging` Python module. The string is nothing special, something like "A special event has occured at". Currently it takes in excess of 20 minutes (which is where I abandoned seeing it through to the end) - acceptable would be a couple of minutes (ideally quicker).

Comment: I would normally use grep for something like this. Consider if you're on Linux or MaxOS - you can combine the output with a python code (e.g use grep and a bash script to create a list of files that have the string). Not pretty, but works much faster.

Comment: @atru is there a grep implementation which does not require interating over every line?

Comment: Might be faster to process larger chunks (like 1 MB) instead of individual lines. If the string has length n, then prepend the previous chunk's n-1 last characters to the current chunk in order to cover the case where the string spans two chunks.

Comment: grep is super efficient and afaik, written in C. I was in situations where the text file was large, and grep would end up being seemingly fastest to do searches like this. But I haven't checked rigorously.

Comment: Why are your log files 10+GB? That defeats the purpose of being able to look in the log file to find whatever you need to find.

Comment: then I would look into using `pandas` - and read a chunk of the file at a time. `for chunk in pd.read_csv(file, use_col['target_column'], chunksize=50000)` There is no way you'll be able to parse string with vanilla python in the size of 10GB in a few minutes.

Comment: Try it out on a single file `cat your_file | grep "the_word" ` - I used it for large datasets from various simulations. Too large by mistake.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Unfortunately I cannot think of a way to answer that question without revealing too much organisational information, but there's a good reason for logs being large, and operationally it takes seconds to search through them using licensed business software

Comment: @Manakin *" There is no way you'll be able to parse string with vanilla python in the size of 10GB in a few minutes."* - I have no idea how you could get such an idea.

Comment: Okay, given the above comments I'll give some grep attempts outside of Python and consider the speed before looking into chunking or mmap Python approaches.

Comment: @KellyBundy see comment above by OP "acceptable would be a couple of minutes (ideally quicker)"

Comment: @Manakin I'm talking about your "There is no way" claim.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'll be be very happy to be proven wrong but given that this is a LOG file and they tend to be verbose (lots of string to parse) I'd be very sceptical of any solution in python that can work on a 10Gb file in a few minutes.Can you direct me to any resources

Comment: @Manakin See my answer.

Comment: @KellyBundy your answer is not demonstrative as 1) we don't know the shape of the log file, 2) I just ran your code on a 4GB with (2mil x 24 cols) csv on my machine on my okay specced laptop and it's still running (3 minutes so far)

Comment: @Manakin Not sure what you mean with "demonstrative", but I do believe I did demonstrate that "There is no way" is wrong. What search string did you use?

Comment: @Manakin And can you tell what times you get with [this benchmark](https://repl.it/@sp0/search-string-in-file#main.py)?

Comment: @Manakin Do you maybe have some antivirus insisting to slowly scan the data before letting Python have it? Or some other limiting factor? 4GB really shouldn't take over 3 minutes or even just anywhere near that long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html):

```
>>> import mmap
>>> import re
>>> f = open("data.log", "r")
>>> mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
>>> re.search(b"test", mm)
<re.Match object; span=(12, 16), match=b'test'>
```

Comment: Having tested it, this mmap solution is quick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you’re on Linux or BSD (Mac) I would just create a subprocess with grep or awk and let them do the search, they have had decades of optimisation for finding strings in big files. Make sure to include commandline flag to tell it to stop searching after the first match, if you only care that it exists and don’t need all instances or a count.

Comment: I, and the users that this software is intended for, are on Windows. However, grep isn't limited to just Linux or BSD, but I cannot speak for the speed differences across OSes.

Answer (score 1):

Try handling larger chunks instead of individual lines. For example:

```
def contains(filename, some_string):
    n = len(some_string)
    prev_chunk = ''
    with open(filename) as f:
        while chunk := f.read(2 ** 20):
            if some_string in prev_chunk[-(n-1):] + chunk:
                return True
            prev_chunk = chunk
        return False
```

I tried that with some made up 1 GB file and it took about 1 second to check a string that's not in there.

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to be going well for me so far - running it on a 100 MB file since 5 minutes ago and it's still going

Comment: @IrregularUser Something must be going very wrong there (and not because of the bug I'm going to fix now :-)

Comment: @IrregularUser Please try the version [here](https://repl.it/@sp0/search-string-in-file#main.py), where I included some progress-printing. What happens with that on the 100 MB file?

Comment: After running it for 15 seconds it's hit 11 billion in the output so far

Comment: @IrregularUser Does it increase in 1 MB steps or smaller?

Comment: Yep the steps are around 1 MB

Comment: @IrregularUser Wait... I thought you said "million" instead of "billion". 11 billion in 15 seconds sounds like good speed. But it shouldn't get to 11 billion in a 100 MB file, as that's 11000 MB. Are you sure?

Comment: Yes something isn't right here - it easily ticks over into the hundred billions while looking for a string, but it definitely quickly finds strings in the first line of the log. The output for this easy test is 113,409,090 though. Looking at the initial output for an actual string that I'm looking for: 113,409,090 is followed by 1,048,576 and 2,097,152 etc (that 113,409,090 is unexpected)

Comment: @IrregularUser Are you saying it keeps going after it found the string?

Comment: So to make it clear I ran two tests - one where the string was at the start of the log (this output only 113,409,090), and another where the string was quite deep in the log (this output 113,409,090; 1,048,576; 2,097,152 etc)

Comment: @IrregularUser But are you looking in the 100 MB file and it goes into the billions for that?

Comment: Yep it's still for the 100MB file, which is why it doesn't make sense. To sanity check, for your 1GB test, is your maximum output sensible (i.e. 1 billion)?

Comment: @IrregularUser Yes, it goes up to 1 GB and then stops. Can you run my [updated benchmark](https://repl.it/@sp0/search-string-in-file#main.py) on your machine and tell what happens? (That's reduced to 100 MB because of repl.it's limits)

Comment: There's a strange line 1 syntax error with the updated benchmark this time

Comment: @IrregularUser That can't be true. Not with my code. You must've changed something.